# Custom methods in an sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What I want is to get the entities from the ShipProperties table and boil down information from the ShipPropertiesVisibility table to get simple entities `can_see` and `can_edit` stating whether the user can see or edit the property, respectively.

Basically something like this (where I am trying to use python methods from the same module) except this is not working syntactically:

```
def get_properties(ship_internal_id, user_id, company_id):
    ship_properties = db.session.query(ShipProperties, 
            _can_see(ShipPropertiesVisibility.visible 
                    if ShipPropertiesVisibility is not None else None) \
                .label("can_see"), 
            _can_edit(ShipAccess.view_only, ShipPropertiesVisibility.editable 
                    if ShipPropertiesVisibility is not None else None) \
                .label("can_edit"))
            ...
    return ship_properties

def _can_see(visible):
    return visible is None or visible is True

def _can_edit(ship_access_view_only, editable):
    return ship_access_view_only is False \
        and (editable is None or editable is True)
```

I also tried the following since my `_can_see` and `_can_edit` functions are just simple combinations of `and` and `or` operators:

```
ship_properties = db.session.query(ShipProperties, 
        func.or_(ShipPropertiesVisibility.visible == None,
                ShipPropertiesVisibility.visible == True) \
            .label("can_see"), 
        func.and_(ShipAccess.view_only == False,
                or_(ShipPropertiesVisibility.editable == None,
                    ShipPropertiesVisibility.editable == True)) \
            .label("can_edit"))\
        ...
```

But with this I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "or"
LINE 1: ...groups, properties.private AS properties_private, or(ship_pr...
```

I also looked into [hybrid properties and methods](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), but I don't think those will work since the ShipPropertiesVisibility entity can be None (meaning the property can both be seen and edited by the user) in which case I don't believe I could call a method or property.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Am I close to a solution and just missing the correct syntax or is this a profound error in thinking, and I should rather be looking into e.g. transforming the sqlalchemy result into a view model, or something else?

Comment: What is the relationship between ShipProperties, ShipPropertiesVisibility and ShipAccess? Why can't you achieve this with a simple join and find the properties by iterating over the records fetched?

Comment: ShipAccess has a column `view_only` which states on a ship level (a ship has many properties) whether ShipProperties can be edited or only viewed (as the name suggests). ShipPropertiesVisibility holds a record for each exception to the specification in ShipAccess, e.g. stating that a property can neither be edited nor viewed. These tables can become quite big so I would like avoid iterating over the whole list where I can. Also in order to hide database implementation of these viewing/editing rights from higher level functions.

Comment: Your custom method doesn't going to reduce the number of records that will be fetched. You are only changing the 'select' part of the query not the 'where' part which actually does the filtering. So you can actually achieve this by iterating the fetched rows.

Comment: Yes but iterating over the fetched rows is time consuming so I'm trying to find a solution where I don't have to iterate.  I think I found a solution, will post it here shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to use the boolean sql operators by utilizing the generic `.op()` method.

```
ship_properties = db.session.query(ShipProperties, Properties, 
        ((ShipPropertiesVisibility.visible == None) \
            .op("OR")(ShipPropertiesVisibility.visible)) \
            .label("can_see"),
        (ShipAccess.view_only == False)
            .op("AND")((ShipPropertiesVisibility.editable == None) \
                .op("OR")(ShipPropertiesVisibility.editable)) \
            .label("can_edit"))\
```